# In Apache Flume Can I write Sink specific interceptor for a single source?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have this particular scenario

Avro Source -> Memory Channel - > Sink1 , Sink2 , Sink 3

Now I need to do some changes to original event for which I added one interceptor.
But I need to make sink specific changes. How can I achieve this ?

How can I write multiple interceptors which to single source which are specific to sink. 
Example :

Original Event from source = "abc"
Interceptor1 converts it to "abc1" and this data is sent to sink1
Interceptor2 converts it to "abc2" and this data is sent to sink2
Interceptor3 converts it to "abc3" and this data is sent to sink3

Comment: Can you be little more specific on your question?

Comment: For example the data from source is "abc" and I want to intercept this data and change it to abc1 for sink1 , abc2 for sink 2 and abc3 for sink3. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781508/filtering-log-files-in-flume-using-interceptors shows how to select a channel based on content.  When your interceptor changes the data can you choose different channels which are connected to different sinks?

Comment: And this: https://questforthought.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/using-flume-interceptor-multiplexing/