# How to filter multiple source data using Apache Flume?

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am using flume to handle multiple sources data and stored in HDFS but I could not understand how to filter data before storing in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use Flume interceptor, check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781508/filtering-log-files-in-flume-using-interceptors).
- Use streaming based solution([Apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html#spark-streaming-flume-integration-guide), Apache Heron/Storm) to filter records then store it in HDFS,

2nd Option give you more flexibility to write different types of streaming patterns. Add comment if you have more queries.